# Navigation drawer combined with google maps crashes

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

I tried to launch the navigation drawer with google maps, but from some reason it crashes me. (It doesn't even load the first map).
I think the problem is about the adapter or about the xml's files.
The LogCat says that the problem is at line 102 :

```
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
```

But I can't find what's wrong it this line. 
I Attaching the xml fils, the Java and the LogCat.
I followed excatly as it mentioned in the offical Android Developer site... but I still don't get what's wrong in my code.
I suspect it's about one of the XML. maybe the Fragment FrameLayout need to change with the FrameLayout of the map that in the drawerlayout.xml ?
I'm a little confused. what can be the soulution to make the application run without crashing?(it crashes run away, and doesn't load the map)
Thank you.

drawer_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
```

activitymain.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

MainActivity.Java

```
  import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    // maps&location global variables
    GoogleMap map;
    public double longitude;
    public double latitude;
    Location location;

    // navigation drawer global variables
    private String[] mNavigationTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // get location code
        final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        final LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        final Location location = lm
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        // animates the camera in zoom 7 to the location of the user
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng UserLoc = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(UserLoc, 7));
        }
        // else {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cant get loc",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // }

        // LocationButtonListener
        map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
                // if the Gps is off it openes a dialog to turn it off
                if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    buildAlertMessageNoGps();
                } else /* if (location == null) */{
                    // if it on, animates to the current position
                    final Location location = lm
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                                    .getLongitude()), 15));
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // navigation drawer declarations&adapter
        mNavigationTitles = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.Navigation_Drawer);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_layout, mNavigationTitles));
        // Set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.firstlogo, R.string.Yes, R.string.no) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        // end of OnCreate function
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the planet to show based on
        // position

        switch (position) {
        case 1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cant get loc",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mNavigationTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the
        // map.
        if (map == null) {
            map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            if (map != null) {
            }
        }
    }

    // function that opened an activity to turn on the GPS
    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("GPS is off ")
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                                    final int id) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                            final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

}
```

LogCat:

```
 06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nir.rauch.flantir/nir.rauch.flantir.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at nir.rauch.flantir.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:102)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
06-05 12:15:53.816: E/AndroidRuntime(22316):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is at line `102`?

Comment: @SimplePlan this is line 102 : "        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this," that sets the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

your actual problem is on below line
replace

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

with

```
setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);
```

you bind wrong xml and you do not load fragment and drawer on same acivity
also comment all map code in on create and put it on your new fragment class... and load map on fragment class not in activity class.

Comment: I changed it to "extends Fragment" but the eclipse shows me a lot of errors. can you describe it more detailed please?I also so that there is a possiblity to do it with Activity(on the demo from the Android Developer site)

Comment: no i think you dont understand what can i say.extend Activity is ok just create new class 'MyMapFragment extend Fragment' and remove all load map code in main activity. and put all code in MymapFragment class. and in drawer first child is your MyMapFragment class.call your first drawer child means MyMapFragment.thats it

Comment: Thanks again. The problems starts when I want to call fucntion from the FragmentActivty Of my Map. It shows me a lot of errors.I don't want load just the fragment, I want to load all of the "Activity".

Comment: why are you dont understand you do not load map with drawer on same tome there are two different things you do simultaneously

Comment: my suggestion is first just create drawer with 3 fragment and move that fragments with drawer list.